# Gradle not working android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I keep getting this error when I try to run my app . It's telling me

```
To run dex in process, the Gradle daemon needs a larger heap.
It currently has approximately 989 MB.
For faster builds, increase the maximum heap size for the Gradle daemon to   more than 2048 MB.
To do this set org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048M in the project gradle.properties.
```

I've been getting this error since earlier in the morning and I still can't fix it . I looked online for answers and I even tried reinstalling android studio but nothing is working . I changed the heap size and added lines to end of the code but nothing is working for me . Can someone please help ? I'm using the latest version of AS.

Comment: where did you add the heap size?

Comment: please have look in that question, if that is not helping then raise new question with all you error log

Comment: @Newbiee tried that it doesn't work

Comment: @Sharj I followed what was in the comment Newbiee just commented

Comment: did you tried setting -Xmx2048M   ??

Comment: # org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048M ? yes I did

Comment: @ban23 `#` means it's a comment. you have to write it without it.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue before. Try to put this in your Module build.gradle:

```
android {   
     ...
    defaultConfig {
        // Enabling multidex support.
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    dexOptions {
        incremental true
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
}


dependencies {

    ....

    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
}
```